# Limit discount in ruby

Tags: ruby

I've got a discount script which applies a discount if a product has a certain tag and another specific is in the cart.
This is the code:

```
products_needed = [1574879461479,1574879461468]
products_seen = []

Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
  product = line_item.variant.product
  products_seen << product.id if products_needed.include?(product.id)
end

@percent = Decimal.new(50) / 100.0
Input.cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
product = line_item.variant.product
next unless product.tags.include?('Giftset1-Item')
line_discount = line_item.line_price * @percent
line_item.change_line_price(line_item.line_price - line_discount, message: "bundle")if products_seen.uniq.sort == products_needed.uniq.sort
end

Output.cart = Input.cart
```

This works well. However, I need to limit the discount to two products, so if a third item is added with the same tag, it shouldn't discount the last item.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Remember that you applied a discount, e.g. by setting a variable `discount_applied = true`. Then only apply a discount if that variable isn't `true`.

Comment: I'd probably split the script into 3 stages: 1) collect all possible discounts, 2) filter out duplicate / incompatible discounts, 3) actually apply discounts to the line items